# Select nodes that have one descendent with a condition AND one descendent with a different condition?

Tags: jquery

Let `$Collection` be a Jquery object. I would like to `find()` within the collection, all `li` elements where the `li` has at least one descendant of `class-a` that also has `class-b` **and** one descendent of `class-a` of the same `li` that does **not** have `class-b`.

**Pseudo code**:

```
$Collection.find('li').
has(DESCENDANT HAVING .class-a.class-b AND ANOTHER DESCENDANT HAVING .class-a:not(.class-b));
```

How do I make a selector that has an `AND ANOTHER DESCENDANT` operator where both conditions must be true for the node to be included in the selection?